# App suddenly logs in / signs up as Facebook anonymous user, not providing public_profile

Tags: android, facebook

Starting the 13th of February, my app's Facebook developers dashboard started generating the following alert:

> In the last three hours 100% of the calls to the method GET {anonymous-user-id}/permissions resulted in errors.
>
> Error Code
> 412
>
> Error Description
> User has not installed the application
>
> Error Count
> 345
>
> This may be result of a recent change you made to Airtasker, or a failure to comply with a recent breaking change.
>
> For more information about error codes and recovery tactics, please visit our documentation.
>
> If the error rate has not been resolved after 3 days, we'll send you another alert.

The backend request for public profile (using the token from the Android app) returns the following:

> error='FbGraph2::Exception::InvalidRequest: This API is not allowed for anonymous users

Obviously the Android app requests anonymous login token somehow/for some reason.
Without the `public_profile` permission.

I was wondering if anyone else encountered the same issue or knows how to recreate anonymous login.

Using Graph API > 2.2

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/173424853153369/

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same problem on our app.  I have yet to find any evidence of this happening in the app though I have also ruled out the backend oAuth flow so it has to be getting triggered inside the app.  I suspect it may be related to older Facebook SDKs on older builds that are still out in the wild.

Then just as suddenly as it apparead this error has dramatically declined since mid February and is basically gone as of .  I wonder are you still seeing the issue